# Настройка переменных PATH для Composer и Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, openserver, path

Не могу настроить пути и чтобы установить Lavarel (а перед этим Composer) на локальный сервер OpenServer. Сейчас такие настройки стоят.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Потом попробовал с гитхаба скачать готовый архив и выдаёт следующие ошибки:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавьте Composer в PATH:

```
C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin\
```

А сама проблема заключается в том, что вы не установили зависимости:

```
composer install // в директории lavar.test
```

Comment: Узнать из командной строки, где находится composer: ``where composer``